What is the criteria for doubling the verse "ויהי נועם" in the Tefila?
There are cases, usually after "יהי רצון" (May there be a desire), that double the verse "ויהי נעם ה' אלקינו עלינו ומעשה ידינו כוננה עלינו ומעשה ידינו כוננהו. ". On the other hand, there are cases in which the verse appears only once, such as on Motsaei Shabbat and in the Kriat Shema reading on the bed? Why is it customary to double and in which places and why are there places where there is no doubling of the verse?

ben ish hai mikketz 8 https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Ish_Hai%2C_Halachot_1st_Year%2C_Miketz.8.1
